# How to make Firefox OS Simulator see localhost & virtual hosts ...

Tags: firefox, localhost, simulator

there,

Shortly: I can' t access neither localhost nor any virtual host, on the Firefox OS Simulator. (Although - I'm able to open 127.0.0.1) So, is there any setting I have to make in order to achieve this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution just now ... pretty stupid :D ... 
when I enter the address with "http://" at the beginning - then it opens it ... otherwise it searches for it ... 
(facepalm) ...